is it possible to stop windows 11 from going to sleep/shutdown when closing the lid?
Quite often I need to leave running computational intensive programs on my laptop for hours or days. I would like to leave the laptop with the lid closed but when I do it the laptop goes to sleep/shutdown (I actually don't know which one is it but the programs are not there). This is despite the fact that I changed what closing the lid does in settings
lid options, and having Power toys Awake set to "keep Away indefinitely". How can I make sure the laptop stays up?
In case it's useful here is some info about my system:
Windows 11 23H2
OS build 22631.3527
XPG Xenia 15
i7-11800H

@John Thanks you for your comment. I was actually only thinking that it was a windows configuration problem, but thanks to your comment I did some testing and apparently the particular software that I was running caused the pc to crash. With other programs it goes keeps awake for hours

Blocking Sleep/ Shutdown/ Hibernate/ Log off
You can do this using little portable app like Don't Sleep

you can customize the setting as you want.
Tested on Windows 11.
